# BigQuery INSERT DML statement limitation

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking at BigQuery dcumentation  here https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-manipulation-language ,and I found that the limit on INSERT and UPDATE is 1000 operations /day / table .

Is this limit only effective when you are using the WebUI for BigQuery or is it also a limit when using the streaming API to insert thousands of queries / second ?

Or is the documentation out of date ?

Answer (score 2):

This is the restriction on using DML (INSERT, UPDATE & DELETE) in your SQL queries (web UI or via API).

This is seperate to the streaming limits which are listed [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quota-policy#streaminginserts).